# Grep match on finding regular expression matches other than known strings

Tags: linux, regex, grep

I have a bunch of .sql files and in quite a few of them we use package I wrote called 'carlmann_demo'. Whatever file uses such package will do as follows:

```
-- This line will be present in every file that uses carlmann_demo
exec carlmann_demo.testProlog;

-- Uses of carlmann_demo other than testProlog, testEpilog like the ones below are optional
carlmann_demo.releaseReport;
carlmann_demo.canBeAnything;

-- This line will be present in every file that uses carlmann_demo
exec carlmann_demo.testEpilog;
```

What I want to do is come up with a way of listing the files that are having optional uses of 'carlmann_demo' (i.e. files that **have words matching carlmann_demo.* other than "carlmann_demo.testProlog" , "carlmann_demo.testEpilog"**).

I have tried as follows but it has not worked since it list all files that use carlmann_demo:

```
grep -sRl "carlmann_demo" | grep -v "carlmann_demo.testEpilog" | grep -v "carlmann_demo.testProlog"
```

I am pretty sure this can be done on the terminal via grep but so far I have not succeeded.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd grep works on file names not contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all occurrences of `carlmann_demo.testProlog` and `carlmann_demo.testEpilog` with empty strings and only then search for `carlmann_demo.`.

```
find . -type f -name '*.sql' -exec sh -c '
    <"$1" sed "s/carlmann_demo\.testProlog//g; s/carlmann_demo\.testEpilog//g" \
    | grep -qF "carlmann_demo."
' find-sh {} \; -print
```

Notes:

- The solution runs one `sh` per one file tested. This is slow and may be improved with `-exec … +` and more complicated shell code (including a loop and conditional printing the filename). I decided to keep it simple; this way you can add more tests after `-exec` or use `-print0` instead of `-print` if you need.
- If your `grep` supports `-m` then use `-m 1` to make it exit after the first match. Additional matches cannot change the result, so processing beyond the first match is futile.
- In regular expressions the dot (`.`) matches (almost) any character. This is the reason behind `grep -F` (match using fixed strings) and behind `\.` (escaped dot) in my `sed` script.